# How to use default VPN instead of Pulse Secure VPN on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: vpn, openvpn

What should be considered if you want to use Ubuntu's default* VPN instead of Pulse Secure.

In Pulse Secure(9.1R) for Ubuntu 20.04 to connect, you must provide only URL and it prompts for username and password.

On the other hand for the Ubuntu's VPN

[image]

Both options require Gateways and more, not just a single URL.

The pulse client is installed without any additional settings or options.

**Edit**:
By “default” I mean from the network settings. It allows you to add configurations and connect.

**Edit2**: “built-in” is a better term, default is maybe con.

Comment: What is 'Ubuntu's default VPN'?

Comment: From the network settings

Comment: There is none in the picture you've posted. Where do you see 'Ubuntu's default VPN'?

Comment: @mikewhatever when you install Pulse Secure Vpn it asks only for URL for the VPN. When you choose any of the listed it asks for much more.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see on your screenshot, Network Manager's "Add VPN connection" dialog supports OpenVPN and PPTP VPN.
Pulse Secure VPN is not compatible with any of these, therefore it needs a dedicated client. You cannot connect to Pulse Secure using built-in Linux VPN support.

Answer (score 1):

The "Pulse Connect Secure" option is present with Ubuntu 22.04.
I've gotten it to work and it is saving the passwords, which is my main reason to use it.

Comment: But how did you make it work?

Comment: I created a VPN definition in the network menu. It asked me for the first- and second- passwords when I connected, and saved them when the connection was made. Also, in my case the second password is always the same, the connection kicks off a Duo handshake.
Are you using Ubuntu 22.04 now?

Comment: I'm wondering if there needs to be some package installed on the system, though, for the Pule Secure option to show up in the VPN menu.

Comment: The menu you show above, the 22.04 equivalent had an option "Multi-protocol VPN client (OpenConnect)". When I selected this, the secondary menu listed "PulseSecure" as one of the settings.

Comment: I had to install these packages to get the pulse secure connect option
`apt install network-manager-openconnect network-manager-openconnect-gnome`

Comment: Does the VPN work for you, then?